# How to create the codeigniter active record for the following query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

How to create the codeigniter active record for the following query?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `student`JOIN `pay_log` ON 
`student`.`student_id` = `pay_log`.`student_id` WHERE (`activity` LIKE '%yr%' 
OR `activity` LIKE '%yr1%') AND `class_id` = 'cl123' AND `student`.`status` = 'active'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      $query = $this->db
              ->select()
              ->from( 'student as s' )
              ->join( 'pay_log as p', 's.student_id = p.student_id' )
              ->where( 'activity LIKE "%yr%" OR activity LIKE "%yr1%"', FALSE )
              ->where( 'class_id', 'cl123' )
              ->where( 's.status', 'active' )
              ->get();
```

Comment: this is not helping. the the bracket part is inside where. Here it is something different.

Comment: I have removed the second option, the one showing provides the likes within the where brackets